# Как сделать выделение объекта при ховере?

Tags: html, css

Как перекрывать блоки в зависимости от наведения?

Например, при ховере на "БЛОК В" должен появляться желтый слой поверх картинки. И так  для каждого элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример вашего кода и уточните - что и при наведении на что должно "появляться"?

Comment: тег `<map> ` в помощь

Comment: если подойдет решение на jquery, могу чуть позже расписать как реализую подобные решения

Comment: @Cheg типа такого надо сделать http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

Answer (score 1):

Допустим блоки находятся в одном контейнере (item, block-b).
Добавляем псевдокласс `hover` на эти элементы. И изменяем их прозрачность (`opacity`),   порядок наложения (`z-index`), и цвет (`background`), если необходимо

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width:700px;
  height:400px;
  position:relative;
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg);
    z-index:999;
}

.item {
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background:#e1e1e1;
  opacity:0.4;
  position:relative;
}

.item:hover {
  background:red;
   opacity:1;
   z-index:2;
}

.block-b {
 position: absolute;
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 bottom:0;
 background:yellow;
 opacity: 0.5;
 z-index:1;
}

.block-b:hover {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="block-b">b</div>
</div>
```